# Displaying the preferred accelerator in MFC feature pack menus and tooltips

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

We have converted an existing MFC application to use the MFC Feature Pack, retaining menus and toolbars rather than ribbons. It has two shortcuts defined in the accelerator resources for Cut, Ctrl+X and Shift+Delete. The older version of the program advertises the preferred shortcut of Ctrl+X in the second column of the menu and in brackets at the end of the tooltip for the toolbar icon. The feature pack, however, sets these up for itself by calling CKeyboardManager::FindDefaultAccelerator(), which returns Shift+Delete.

Is there a way to set up the accelerator resources so that the program displays the preferred shortcut, or some other way?

Comment: Did you try to change the order they appear in the .rc file and deleted the `Workspace` folder from your registry after?

Comment: I have tried that suggestion and it makes no difference.